# Why does my post not load the photos when creating?

Tags: asp.net, post, cloudinary

I created an app with some posts about charity. I made a POST method for creating new posts. This posts contain a title, some text and some photos. However, when I am creating the post, the frontend will show everything except for the photos I've loaded(using cloudinary), with no errors in the console. When I am trying to test my create post method in Postman I receive a 415-Unsupported Media Type error and I have not been able to figure the problem out for some days now. I am loading the photos as form-data in Postman.
This is my photo service:

```
 public class PhotoService : IPhotoService
    {
        private readonly Cloudinary _cloudinary;
        public PhotoService(IOptions<CloudinarySettings> config)
        {
            var acc = new Account
                (
                    config.Value.CloudName,
                    config.Value.ApiKey,
                    config.Value.ApiSecret
                );
            _cloudinary = new Cloudinary(acc);
        }

        public async Task<ImageUploadResult> AddPhotoAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();
            
            if(file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();

                
                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, stream),
                    Transformation = new Transformation().Height(500).Width(500).Crop("fill")
                };

                uploadResult = await _cloudinary.UploadAsync(uploadParams);
            }
            return uploadResult;
        }
```

This is my create post method:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PostDto>> CreatePost(PostDto postDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Not a valid model");
            var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(User.GetUsername());

            var post = new Post
            {
                Title = postDto.Title,
                Text = postDto.Text,
                UserId = user.Id,
                Photos = postDto?.Photos
            };

            _context.Posts.Add(post);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new PostDto
            {
                Title = post.Title,
                Text = post.Text,
                UserId = post.UserId,
                Photos = post?.Photos
            };
        }
```

And this is my method to add a photo in my PostController:

```
 [HttpPost("add-photo")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PhotoDto>> AddPhoto(IFormFile file, int id)
        {
            var post = await _postRepository.GetPostByIdAsync(id);
            var result = await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(file);

            if (result.Error != null) return BadRequest(result.Error.Message);

            var photo = new Photo
            {
                Url = result.SecureUrl.AbsoluteUri,
                PublicId = result.PublicId
            };

            post.Photos.Add(photo);

            if (await _postRepository.SaveAllAsync())
            {
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetPost", new { id = post.Id }, _mapper.Map<PhotoDto>(photo)); ;
            }

            return BadRequest("Problem adding photo");
        }
```

What is wrong with my code? I've done some research, but I have not been able to detect the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: So did the upload to your Cloudinary account is it actually successful or failed? Can you see the uploaded asset when you login to Cloudinary's console?
Is the 415 error coming from Cloudinary response when you tried to upload?

Comment: No, the images are not loading to my Cloudinary account. This is the response in Postman: {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|df6c48e-4bde8c444066c8f8."
}

Comment: I recommend to open a [support ticket](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with the details and including the image that you are trying to upload so they can take a look what's happening behind the scene.